# Chakra-UI Text component noOfLines doesn't display right in Safari

Tags: reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

I havea a Chakra-UI Text component in a Next.js TypeScript web app. The noOfLines doesn't display right in Safari, but correct in Chrome. Any suggestions?

```
<Box pt={3} width={'100%'}>
    <Text noOfLines={show ? 0 : 2}>
        <ReactMarkdown>{collection.description}</ReactMarkdown>
    </Text>
    <Button size="sm" onClick={handleToggle} variant={"link"}>
        Show {show ? "Less" : "More"}
    </Button>
</Box>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same stack and problem with `noOfLines` not playing nicely with `ReactMarkdown`. I worked around this by swapping `noOfLines` with `maxHeight`:

```
<Text overflow='hidden' maxHeight={show ? undefined : '5em'}>
```

Note: You'll lose the ellipsis and `textOverflow='ellipsis'` wasn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it with using `overflow` and `maxHeight` properties for Safari :

```
...
const isSafari = typeof navigator !== "undefined" && navigator.userAgent.includes("Safari");
...

              <Text
                noOfLines={4}
                overflow={isSafari ? "hidden" : undefined}
                maxHeight={isSafari ? "85px" : undefined}
              >
                <ReactMarkdown disallowedElements={["img"]}>
                  {props.data.content}
                </ReactMarkdown>
              </Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple case where you most likely don't even need Chakra. You need to set a width/height on the string itself before it can be truncated. See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/